# Highly upvoted answer on highly upvoted question is totally wrong?

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

I just closed another question as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2942426/2069064), but when reading through what the top answer was - something is totally off here. This is (as of this writing) a +73 question with a +77 answer that doesn't at all answer the question and has been wrong for nearly the entirety of the question's existence.

The timeline helps explain what happened:

- May 31, 2010 8:55am - question is asked about passing an overloaded free function
- 8:57am - answer is posted answering the question. The answer was correct.
- 9:12am - question is edited to ask about member functions instead
- 9:12am - note added to answer about dealing with member functions (it's unclear if the note was just a followup edit to the answer or a response to the question edit).

The note added to the answer is insufficient to actually answer the question as it currently stands. So the answer is just... wrong. Most of its upvotes have come long after the question changed to be about member functions too.

So... what do you do here? One option I've considered is that since none of the answers directly answer the question with regards to member functions (three provide solutions that work with both versions of the question, two only work with free functions) is to actually roll back the question to ask about free functions instead. Does that seem legit?

Or just do nothing?

Comment: If you feel the edit invalidated the answer then you have to rollback as it is not acceptable. I lack the knowledge to decide here though.

Comment: Not sure it would be appropriate or not based on site guidelines and it would be asking two related question but can we edit the Q to ask how to do it for free functions and member functions?  Then any answer to either or both still works.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was considering editing the question to ask both, and editing the top answer to add more details to the `mem_fn` comment so that it works for the member function case. But mostly leaning towards: do nothing.

Comment: @Bakuriu I think Tunaki means rolling back the *question* edit to be the initial question (referring to free functions).

Comment: @Barry Ah, okay that could make sense. Not sure in this specific case though.

Comment: Even if you do nothing to the question,why not at least provide feedback to the author, e.g. in a comment, about better ways to ask questions.

Answer (score 11):

The only answer here is really to use your common sense.  In this specific case, I don't think that you need to change anything.

You need to consider the ultimate goal of questions and answers on this site, which is to help future users.  Since a bunch of votes came in long after the question was answered, it has probably helped numerous people, so you should not have to do anything about the answer.

It is probably also the case that the question is worded in such a way that the right people still found it.

It is also true that there are other up-voted answers on the question.  I didn't look at all of them, but they might have addressed the OP's last version of the question.

---

Sometimes, you get true chameleon questions, and sometimes there are other errors with the question, such as the OP using terminology incorrectly or the OP omitting code that actually matters.   This question seems to be the latter of the two cases, so in my opinion this specific question should not be rolled back.

The latter version of the question likely represents the true problem the OP had.  It is my opinion that the actual problem is the problem that should be exemplified with the question.  It keeps the solutions on SO more "organic", for lack of a better word.

---

If you came to that question, because you were experiencing the same problem yourself, and if the top answer probably solves **a** problem but not the problem you had and not the problem the OP had, then go ahead and downvote without shame.  In the long term, The answer's score should be a representation of how many people it actually helped vs how many people it  did not help.  You do not need to speculate on who it may or may not help in the future.  You know of exactly **2** people who the answer might or might not have helped, and that is **you** and **the OP**

Answer (score 4):

[Sam's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321549) provides a good, general way to look at things. The goal should always be to ensure there are useful questions, with useful answers.

As for this specific question, it seems to me that it's clear both the question and answer were found useful by a large number of people. On a site where most questions are lucky to get a handful of votes, getting into the 70's is very good. It's entirely possible that this is a mix of people dealing with free functions and those dealing with class members; there's definitely enough information there for either group to get what they were looking for.

In light of that, I think that rolling back the question would clearly be a step backwards.

If after observing the community support for the current situation, you really want to improve the experience of other Stack Overflow users, it seems to me that the best thing you can do is *not* to rollback the question, but rather to edit it so that it correctly identifies that one is going to require a different solution for free functions than for class members. This would act as a clear signpost to people coming across the question that they need to be on the lookout for a particular solution in the question's answers, depending on their own needs.

You can then also add details to the answer, if necessary, to ensure readers can clearly identify which part of the answer applies to which scenario.

From [your comment here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321534/highly-upvoted-answer-on-highly-upvoted-question-is-totally-wrong?cb=1#comment335919_321534):

> I was considering editing the question to ask both, and editing the top answer to add more details to the mem_fn comment so that it works for the member function case

…it seems that you've at least considered the possibility of doing this. I would encourage you to do so. It seems to me to be the best action one could take in editing the posts involved that would actually make things better.